# remove objects from array by comparing value1 of elements that share value2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many objects in an array. I'd like to take any objects that have the same 'id' and compare the 'num' value with other 'num' values of that same 'id'. I'm looking to reduce the entire array of objects to an array of objects with only the highest number per id. These can be duplicated but any objects that have less than the highest number should be removed. All other key/value pairs should come along for the ride as well in whatever final array of objects is created.

```
{
  random : ajabl,
  num : 5, // should stay, highest number is 5
  id :10
}
{
  random: jlsl,
  num : 4, // should go, highest number is 5
  id : 10 
}
{
  random: jlssssl,
  num : 5, // should stay, highest number is 5
  id : 10
}
{ 
  random: abcd,
  num : 1, // should go, highest number is 5
  id : 10
}
{
  random : xy45,
  num : 2, // Should stay, highest number is 2
  id : 11
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve it using **ES6** by this way:

```js
let arr = [{
  num : 5, // should stay, highest number is 5
  id :10
},
{
  num : 4, // should go, highest number is 5
  id : 10 
},
{
  num : 5, // should stay, highest number is 5
  id : 10
},
{ 
  num : 1, // should go, highest number is 5
  id : 10
},
{
  num : 2, // Should stay, highest number is 2
  id : 11
}];


let ids = Array.from(new Set(arr.map(i => i.id)));

let result = [];
Array.from(new Set(arr.map(i => i.id))).forEach(a => {
  let tmp = arr.filter(i => i.id === a).sort((a,b) => b.num - a.num);
  tmp.filter(i => i.num === tmp[0].num).map(j => result.push(j));
});

console.log(result);
```

The **Set** operator is to remove duplicates.

First get the ids into an array and then loop to get each set of object per array to finally merge them up by adding in the result array

Comment: Apart from the let ids unused var, this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are far better ways to do this, but hey, it's a start :)

```js
var list = [
{
  num : 5, // should stay, highest number is 5
  id :10
},
{
  num : 4, // should go, highest number is 5
  id : 10 
},
{
  num : 5, // should stay, highest number is 5
  id : 10
},
{ 
  num : 1, // should go, highest number is 5
  id : 10
},
{
  num : 2, // Should stay, highest number is 2
  id : 11
}
]
let result = []
for(obj of list) {
    let resultItem = result.find(item => item.id==obj.id)
    if(resultItem==null) {
        //first occurence of this id, keep it
        result.push(obj)
    } else {
        //keep it only if it's greater or equal than the existing num
        if(obj.num >= resultItem.num) {
            result.push(obj)
            //remove the previous ones
            result = result.filter(item => item.id!=obj.id || item.num==obj.num)
        }
    }
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I only get back one result. There are multiple ids and many of id's have multiple  top value results. All of these should be displayed.

Comment: in your example you said items 1, 3 and 5 should stay, and item 2 and 4 should go. My code does exactly what you asked. So I don't understand why it's not ok for you.

Comment: It's definitely ok for me :) It just didn't work against my huge data set for some reason. Most definitely some issue on my part.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [
  {
    num: 5, // should stay, highest number is 5
    id: 10
  },
  {
    num: 4, // should go, highest number is 5
    id: 10
  },
  {
    num: 5, // should stay, highest number is 5
    id: 10
  },
  {
    num: 1, // should go, highest number is 5
    id: 10
  },
  {
    num: 2, // Should stay, highest number is 2
    id: 11
  }
];

var d = a.reduce((c, b) => {
  if (!c[b["id"]]) {
    c[b["id"]] = b["num"];
  } else {
    if (c[b["id"]] < b["num"]) {
      c[b["id"]] = b["num"];
    }
  }
  return c;
}, {});

var e = Object.keys(d).map(function(key) {
  return { id: key, num: d[key] };
});

console.log(e);
```

Comment: This almost worked. It returned each project and the highest num per id but there should be multiple highest nums in some ids that should all be returned as well.

Comment: I see you have updated your question with a 'random' field, it makes more sense now to also add the repeated higher values.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't specific enough in my first draft, was hoping it added more clarity to subsequent readers.